# How to convert a single char in a sliced String into Integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, casting, char, integer

For example, I have a

```
String = "TGR1UK"
```

I only need the number 1 in the string to do some math operation so I make a number variable as

```
number = String[3]
```

but the type of this "number" is actually Char
and I cant use

```
number = (int)String[3]
```

to cast it into an integer

what should I do?

Comment: There *is no char type in python*. And I'm pretty sure `number = (int)String[3]` would raise a syntax error. Why aren't you calling the `int` function? It looks like you are trying to do a C-like cast. Python is not C, there are no casts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number = int(String[3])
```

This will cast it to an int. Read more here:

https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-string-to-int/

Edit:
I have assumed when you said:

> but the type of this "number" is actually Char and I cant use
> `number = (int)String[3]`

That you meant that wasnt working, because that is not how you cast to an int in python. Did you mean you aren't allowed to use a straight cast for some reason?

Comment: Thank you! I just simply misplaced my curly brackets lol

Comment: Those aren't curly brackets btw, these are: `{}`. Those were parentheses or, simply, brackets

Answer (score 0):

You're using `int` wrong. `int` is used as follows:

```
int(string)
```

So, try `number = int(String[3])`.

Comment: Yes, that's the cause, Thank you for answering!